# Cannot run jupyter everywhere (terminal, anaconda distributer) Mac os 10.12.6

Tags: python, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I got a problem with running jupyter in the terminal.

What terminal says after running

```
maxim@MacBook-Pro-Maxim  ~  jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise original_error from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 32, in select_backend
    mod = import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../.dylibs/libsodium.23.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../.dylibs/libsodium.23.dylib
```

I was trying to use Anaconda and got the same issue

For me, it seems to be something wrong with path...

Please help me to resolve it or give a hint of what to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm seeing the exact same issue - seems the zmq package has a /cython/ in it with incompatible references.  Is it not using cython from the site-packages?  I've tried reinstalling cython, pyzmq, and all the jupyter modules with no joy yet.

EDIT - I downgraded pyzmq to 20.0.0 and it worked fine.
`pip install pyzmq==20.0.0`

I believe the issue is in pyzmq's cython packaging - and should be raised as a bug to them.

Comment: Thanks @Penumbra! it works for me too. You made my day, i spent a lot of time to resolve the issue by myself, but nothing worked.

Comment: Bug has been reported and fixed on pyzmq, should be fixed by release 21.0.2