# Jupiter notebook won't start - Symbol not found error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

A while back, I upgraded my python version via brew to 3.9.0 and now, whenever I try to start Jupiter notebook, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise original_error from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 32, in select_backend
    mod = import_module(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../.dylibs/libsodium.23.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../.dylibs/libsodium.23.dylib
```

I've tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling jupiter to no avail. I've also tried reinstalling the zmq module that seems to be a part of this error chain. My thought is that there must be some component that's avoiding my uninstalls that needs to be fixed/updated, but I'm not sure what it could be.

I'm also running MacOS 10.13.6. I notice it states that one of these modules was built for Mac OS X 10.15. Could this instead be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided in this link worked for me:
[Cannot run jupyter everywhere (terminal, anaconda distributer) Mac os 10.12.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65774567/8203755)

"downgraded pyzmq to 20.0.0 and it worked fine. pip install pyzmq==20.0.0

I believe the issue is in pyzmq's cython packaging - and should be raised as a bug to them."

The bug has been raised and is expected to be fixed by release 21.0.2